# Continuously check for focus using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I need to display a div whenever an input box is in focus, and I need this div to be hidden when it is not is focus. I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#inputPassword").is(":focus")){
        $("#passwordInfo").css("display", "block");
    }
    else {
        $("#passwordInfo").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

`#passwordInfo` is the div I am attempting to alter the display.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ with events `blur` and `focus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to listen for the `focus` and `blur` events in your case.

`focus`: Fired when an input element gains focus. For example, when a user clicks on an input element

`blur`: Fired when an input element loses focus. For example, when a user clicks outside of the input element.

```js
var div = $("#text");
div.hide();

$("#input-field").on("focus", function() {
    div.css({ "display": "block" });
}).on("blur", function() {
    div.css({ "display": "none" });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input-field" />

<div id="text">This is text</div>
```

This can actually be simplified using `show()` and `hide()`

```
$("#input-field").on("focus", function() {
    div.show();
}).on("blur", function() {
    div.hide();
});
```

Or combined into one function

```js
var div = $("#text");
div.hide();

$("#input-field").on("focus blur", function(event) {
    div.toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input-field" />

<div id="text">This is text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if ($("#inputPassword").is(":focus"))` code only runs when the document is first ready, so a check is not performed repeatedly.

What you are looking for are the `.focus()` and `.blur()` functions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inputPassword").focus(function() {
        $("#passwordInfo").css("display", "block");
    });
    $("#inputPassword").blur(function() {
        $("#passwordInfo").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```